# How to properly use same text sections across multiple html pages?

Tags: html, text, reference, include

I am making help content documentation for an already made software (the kind of which opens in every software when you press F1 or navigate to the Help section in the menu bar). I am using simple html/CSS/js pages to do so.

There is a ton of the same text descriptions of various software properties that appear in more than one page. The idea is to make a single text source file, where all the text descriptions are located and then use some sort of referencing to that specific text section wherever necessary.

Kind of a similar to using a CSS stylesheet to apply styles over all of the pages, only this handles text instead of styles. This way I would be able to change text in only one file and it would apply everywhere it is used.

I ran across the html SSI method, but this only includes the entire html page and not just a specific text section the way I would like to. I would strongly avoid using different file for each text section.

Can anyone please point me into the right direction here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can make a JavaScript function that contains the common texts and use this functions in your code whenever you need them, for this the JavaScript that you create should be an external file and you can reference it in every html page you need it.

For example, you can have one function that returns "Hello World" and set this to a "p" element with the id="title". So in every page where you have an element with the id title you can call your JavaScript function to set its text to "Hello World". Use this link to find out more about this topic:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

UPDATE: I did a little test, i created the following JavaScript:

```
function helloTitle(){
    var text = "Hello World!";
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = text;
}
```

And referenced it in some HTML pages like this:

```
<script src="commonText.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that i only need to call the function in the element i want it to modify:

```
<p id="title"><script>helloTitle();</script></p>
```

This is a solution if you are only using JS, CSS and HTML. There should be other ways to achieve this.

Hope this information could help you!

Comment: This solution works perfectly! It even allows 2 levels of referencing, by function name and by ID tag, just what I need. Thank you, this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it a little more comforatbly on a large scale using the  html command https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

in your main html file you do:

```html
<p> <iframe src="Text.html" width="100%" height="300" style="border:1px solid black;"> </p>
```

and then with some basic html formating insert whatever text u want

```html
<html>
<body>
    hmm idk what i should put here. Test    
</body>
</html>
```

there will also be some css formatting needing to be done before it look perfect, but if you want to make multi line blocks I think this is the easiest way to.

Comment: I tried this before, but the requirement that one specify the `height=` attribute made it too annoying to be useful.  The height depends on various factors, such as the current window width, the current text size, and the current content of the included page, so the result is almost always either a lot of vertical white space or vertical scrolling. ¶ It would be so much more useful if there were something like a `height="to-fit"`.